# How can I have a two part attribute name with a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            ngChange: "&",
            ngModel: "=",
            options: "="
        },
        template: '<div><span>{{label}}</span><select id="{{id}}" ng-change="ngChange()" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.label = $attrs.spanlabel;
            $scope.id = $attrs.selectid;
        }
    };
});
```

I am calling this directive like this:

```
        <div data-admin-select
             spanlabel="ExamType"
             selectid="examTypeSelect"
             ng-change="ctrl.typeChanged(item)"
             ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.examTypeId"
             options="ctrl.examType.dataPlus"></div>
```

The attribute names spanlabel and selectid are not really what I want. Can I make these into two part names like span-label of if not that spanLabel.  If so then how can I do that?

Comment: I believe that changing the HTML to `<div span-label="...">` will work from the JS side using `$attrs.spanLabel` (note dashes in the HTML, camelCase in the JS).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/tugej/1/edit

html

```
<div data-admin-select
             span-label="ExamType"
             select-id="examTypeSelect"
             ng-change="ctrl.typeChanged(item)"
             ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.examTypeId"
             options="ctrl.examType.dataPlus">
</div>
```

js:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.directive("adminSelect", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                ngChange: "&",
                ngModel: "=",
                options: "="
            },
            template: '<div><span>{{label}}</span><select id="{{id}}" ng-change="ngChange()" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options"></div>',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.label = $attrs.spanLabel;
                $scope.id = $attrs.selectId;
            }
        };
    });
    app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){




    })
```